# Keras: how learning rate changes when Adadelta optimizer is used?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

For example I use `Adadelta` for optimizer when compile network model, then `learning rate` will change in time by this [rule](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L321) (but what is `iterations` ? ) and how can I log learning rate value to console?

```
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
        optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adadelta())
```

In [documentation](https://keras.io/optimizers/#adadelta) `lr` is just starting learning rate?

Answer (score 3):

The rule is related to updates with decay. Adadelta is an adaptive learning rate method which uses exponentially decaying average of gradients.

Comment: Do you mean update rule `lr=lr*alpha`? Anyway `Adadelta` have other parameters.

Comment: Adadelta extends Adagrad to change the way of updating the learning rate. Adagrad updates and scales alpha parameters based on the history of gradients, which lead to monotonically decrease to the learning rate. In the other way, Adadelta restricts the accumulated history of gradients to a fixed size, which is the decaying average of all past squared gradients.

Check the following link for more information:
https://www.quora.com/What-are-differences-between-update-rules-like-AdaDelta-RMSProp-AdaGrad-and-AdaM

Comment: Yes, I understand that each optimizer have it's own learning rate update strategy, for now I just want print/log/view learning rate.

Comment: It can be done using callback and log learning rate on 'on_epoch_end'. 
something like below:
model.fit(..., callbacks=[YourLearningRateTracker()])

also, check the following issue: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2823

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Keras source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py), learning rate is recalculated based on decay like:

```
lr = self.lr
if self.initial_decay > 0:
    lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations, K.dtype(self.decay))))
```

So yes, `lr` is just starting learning rate.

To print it after every epoch, as @orabis mentioned, you can make a callback class:

```
class YourLearningRateTracker(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        lr = self.model.optimizer.lr
        decay = self.model.optimizer.decay
        iterations = self.model.optimizer.iterations
        lr_with_decay = lr / (1. + decay * K.cast(iterations, K.dtype(decay)))
        print(K.eval(lr_with_decay))
```

and then add its instance to the callbacks when calling `model.fit()` like:

```
model.fit(..., callbacks=[YourLearningRateTracker()])
```

However, note that, by default, `decay` parameter for Adadelta is zero and is not part of the “standard” arguments, so your learning rate would not be changing its value when using default arguments.
I suspect that decay is not intended to be used with Adadelta.

On the other hand, `rho` parameter, which is nonzero by default, doesn’t describe the decay of the learning rate, but corresponds to the fraction of gradient to keep at each time step (according to the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/optimizers/)).

I found some relevant information on [this Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7874), and by asking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657393/why-doesnt-the-adadelta-optimizer-decay-the-learning-rate).