# Why doesn't the Adadelta optimizer decay the learning rate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have initialised an Adadelta optimizer in Keras (using Tensorflow backend) and assigned it to a model:

```
my_adadelta = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=0.01, rho=0.95)
my_model.compile(optimizer=my_adadelta, loss="binary_crossentropy")
```

During training, I am using a callback to print the learning rate after every epoch:

```
class LRPrintCallback(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        lr = self.model.optimizer.lr
        print(K.eval(lr))
```

However, this prints the same (initial) learning rate after every epoch.
The same thing happens if I initialize the optimizer like this:

```
my_adadelta = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=0.01, decay=0.95)
```

Am I doing something wrong in the initialization? Is the learning rate maybe changing but I am not printing the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in a relevant [Github thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7874), the decay does not affect the variable `lr` itself, which is used only to store the initial value of the learning rate. In order to print the decayed value, you need to explicitly compute it yourself and store it in a separate variable `lr_with_decay`; you can do so by using the following callback:

```
class MyCallback(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        lr = self.model.optimizer.lr
        decay = self.model.optimizer.decay
        iterations = self.model.optimizer.iterations
        lr_with_decay = lr / (1. + decay * K.cast(iterations, K.dtype(decay)))
        print(K.eval(lr_with_decay))
```

as explained [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7874#issuecomment-329347949) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7874#issuecomment-329049987). In fact, the specific code snippet suggested there, i.e.

```
lr = self.lr
if self.initial_decay > 0:
    lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations, K.dtype(self.decay))))
```

comes directly from the underlying Keras [source code for Adadelta](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L424).

As clear from the inspection of the linked source code, the parameter of interest here for decaying the learning rate is `decay`, and not `rho`; despite the term 'decay' used also for describing `rho` in the [documentation](https://keras.io/optimizers/), it is a different decay not having anything to do with the learning rate:

> **rho**: float >= 0. Adadelta decay factor, corresponding to fraction of gradient to keep at each time step.

Comment: I saw this Github thread, but user yuyang-huang didn’t provide any source to support their claim.

Comment: @nim.py See updated answer; please notice the `contributor` indication in that user's comments, which means they are active contributors to Keras code.

Comment: That’s a good point. Right, so if I understand correctly (by having a quick look at [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5701.pdf)), Adadelta wasn’t even intended to be used with the non-zero `decay` parameter (and even though Keras supports it, the default value for it is 0).

Comment: @nim.py most probably so; notice also that, although you *can* use `decay`, it is not included in the "standard" arguments as described in the docs.